# Problems/laggy system by pulling ethernet cable

Tags: networking, pi-4, node.js

I have a RPi4 with dietpi node.js express socket.io serving a html-gui to monitor and control some gpios. Using chromium as frontend on the 7" raspberry touch monitor in kiosk mode to display a html-file connected via sockets to the node.js

Using the RPi connected via ethernet to my local network everything runs fast and responds without delays.

Problem occur by pulling the ethernet cable or booting without being connected: - gui stops responding fast, button actions are slow and delayed, gui nearly unusable.

I have tried to disable the NIC, shutdown eth0, setting ip to 127.0.0.1 without any improvement. I dont know which layer or module from the stack depends on a working internet conncetion. DNS? node.js itself?

Every hints or help are welcome!

Comment: DO NOT SET eth0 TO 127.0.0.1. Never. 127.0.0.1 is reserved for loopback.

Comment: This looks like a network issue. When you pull the ethernet cable, I assume it works via WiFi (add a confirmation to your question).  Does the application connect to the WiFi address (which is probably different from the wired address)? Is your name resolution in order? try an `nslookup` of the server name on the client and vice-versa. Is you WiFi just a lot slower? Try to ping on IP address with and without the ethernet cable.

Comment: this has to be the 5th question in about 2 weeks where a raspberry pi 4 either has no wifi or, in this case, poor wifi - when no ethernet is connected - I'm beginning to suspect that there's a batch of pi4 with rubbish wifi!!! I wouldn't know, all my pi4's are ethernet connected and can't test since they're also PoE :p

Comment: The app is running with 127.0.0.1 or localhost as both entires are in the hosts file and with an ethernet connection via cable. Wifi is disabled so no fallback will start by pulling the cable.

Comment: The whole app is designed to work without an ethernet connection. All files are stored on sd-card, node.js is serving some html to chromium. No access from other clients is desired or required.

Comment: For development i use ssh via ethernet of course. Booting the pi without ethernet (production scenario) will end in a slow performance and the app is nearly unusable. Thanx to all your hints!